# Secure Mysql Install can't connect after secure install

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

So I'm following a tutorial on installing vanilla forums and I'm flowering the steps to create root mysql user I follow all steps set everything stop mysql and then restart it now when I try to login with root I get this error

CAN NOT CONNECT TO LOCAL MYSQL SERVER THROUGH socket /car/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (2 "no file or directory exists) but when I try to re run the secure install o get the same error

What do I do to correct this

Comment: The socket name does not look correct. Normally it is `/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock `. Check the MySQL log files for errors starting MySQL (usually /var/log/mysql.log)

Comment: Naive question: Why don't use Cloud SQL ?

Comment: I got it sorted I was stopping it causing the sock issue re ran the install and @blaqhiere I didn't know they had a cloud sql or I would have